# Stretching columns to fill all available space of DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gridview

Is it possible to stretch columns or the last column to fill all the available space of the data grid?

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dataGrid1"   ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
```

My columns are Auto generated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, I think you are looking for the [AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode.aspx) property.

```
int n = grid.Columns.Count;
grid.Columns[n].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

**Edit:** Try setting the width to "*" as seen below.  You'll have to do this in the code if your columns are auto-generated.

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Isn't your answer related to winforms ?

Comment: Yes, but the `DataGrid` in WPF is identical to the `DataGridView` in Winforms.  See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559.aspx

Comment: @user807566: They are not identical, and specifically the AutoSizeMode property doesn't exist on the DataGrid class.

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" /> works fine for me, thanks.

Comment: Why is this the chosen answer? And why does it have so many upvotes?

Answer (score 6):

Since the vast majority of the answers I've found on this topic deal with XAML, here is a C# solution to set all columns to fill the available space in the datagrid.

```
    foreach (var column in this.datagrid.Columns)
    {
        column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach guys, I wrote it this morning, robust and reliable and allows for percentage based width columns taking all available space. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526024/41211

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid.Columns[x].Width = DataGridLength.Auto;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set all column widths to auto except the last column, which should fill the remaining space, try the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == grid.Columns.Count - 1)
    {
        grid.Columns[i].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
    }
    else
    {
        grid.Columns[i].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto); 
    }
}
```