# WPF ListView GridViewColumn width 50% of space

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I got this xaml of a `ListView`:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListViewAgentItems}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="Agent ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AgentId}"/>
                <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="Distance" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Distance}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This is the style:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I want both `GridViewColumn` to take all the space evenly, meaning that the `ListView` is in a grid column, so I want the `GridView` to take the entire column space, and also that both columns of the GridView will take 50% of the width. As of now, the ListView is automatically sized to fit the data it holds which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to a read-only `DataGrid`, you could use [star-sizing](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/star-sizing/):

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListViewAgentItems}" 
          IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Agent ID" Binding="{Binding AgentId}" Width="1*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Distance" Binding="{Binding Distance}" Width="1*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Something strange happens with this solution. The design shows it as I want it to. However when I run the app, it adds more columns automatically with the other field members of the type inside the ListViewAgentItems

Comment: @YonatanNir: Oh, you should add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`. See my edit.

Comment: Why do you need the IsReadOnly? It also works without it

Comment: @YonatanNir: You don't need it if your properties are read-only. Otherwise, you will be able to edit them by double-clicking on the cells and then it no longer behaves as a `ListView`. That's why I added it to the sample markup.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to use a datagrid rather than listview. You can set datagrid xxxx column width to *.

If you really wanted to stick with listview and you don't have a set width so you can set the widths to a specific number, see.
[How can I get a ListView GridViewColumn to fill the remaining space in my grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331940/how-can-i-get-a-listview-gridviewcolumn-to-fill-the-remaining-space-in-my-grid/10526024)